# How to get Soybean commodity price into Google Sheet: Simple solution

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, live, commodity

I went here:
https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/soybeans

I inspect element of the soybean price, visible on the right side.
[image]

Then I find the number in the dev tools panel, right click and copy Xpath, or copy full xpath.

[image]

Then I passed the xpath into a fomula.

1. `=IMPORTXML("https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/soybeans", "//*[@id="p"]/text()")`

OR

2. `=IMPORTXML("https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/soybeans", "/html/body/form/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/text()")`

But I get an error either #NA or #ERROR!

Later I tried here:https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=soybeans&months=60

But this also didn't work:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=soybeans&months=60", "//*[@id="futuresPanel"]/span")`

Comment: worked on https://www.investing.com/commodities/us-soybeans-related-instruments

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76360245/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I also made several tests with that site and got the error:

`Could not fetch url: https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/soybeans`

The issue is that the data you're trying to import is dynamically loaded. This data is loaded by JavaScript, therefore is not retrievable by IMPORT functions in Google Sheets. You can refer to this [thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/169261495/importxml-could-not-fetch-url?hl=en) for more details.

I also found another [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/u8h2iw/importhtml_formula_stopped_working/) regarding the same website and reports the same issue, it seems the website does not allow web scraping.